# Spring rest use of pathVariable and RequestParam

Tags: spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

With spring rest is there any reason to use request param?

For a search i don't know if i shoud use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers/{searchParam}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Lodger getAllLogders(@PathVariable("searchParam") String searchParam)
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Lodger getAllLogders(String searchParam)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I use it, a path (pathVariables) points to a resource.
A queryParam (requestParam) results in a subset of a resource.

If you want certain users from `/Users` (e.g. beginning with "A", or lodgers named "Curt") this would be a subset, of all `/Users` and I see not a very good reason for having a special resource with that criteria, so I would use a queryParam here.